# Making Apache HttpClient 4.3 work with sslSocketFactory/HostnameVerifier

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-commons, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm working on a Java program that will send POST requests to a website for my company to use. We do not own this website, they are separate from us. I've been fighting with various ways to actually pass it the very picky parameters it wants in order for me to do work on it from a program (as opposed to doing it manually).

I've found that the Apache HttpClient 4.3 seems to be my best route for actually trying to access it, anything results in a angry response from the website telling me my username and password and not valid/authorized.

But then I got an error because the site certificate doesn't match, I contacted their support and they reportedly share an infrastructure with another site so the certificate mismatch is expected.

So I went commandline and generated a keystore, passed that to the program and then got the error "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching".

Some hunting lead me to utilize a verifier, which removed errors.

Then I realized that I can't make URLConnection/HttpsURLConnection and HttpClient/HttpPost work together. That's where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to make the code that handles my keystore, TrustManager, SSLSocketFactory, etc  connect to the part where I actually have to connect and POST.

Code that handles the certificates and verification:

```
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\my.keystore")); 
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()); 
    ks.load(in, "blahblah".toCharArray()); 
in.close(); TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
    tmf.init(ks);
     X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0]; 
     SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
     context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {defaultTrustManager}, null); 
     javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

URL url = new URL("https://emailer.driveclick.com/dbadmin/xml_post.pl"); 

     URLConnection con = url.openConnection(); 
    ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory); 
   ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setHostnameVerifier(new Verifier());
     con.connect(); 
    in = con.getInputStream();
```

Code that should be connecting me to the website:

```
 try {
        //log into the website

        String url2 = "https://emailer.driveclick.com/dbadmin/xml_post.pl";
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();



        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url2);


        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<BasicNameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "namefoo"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_password", "passfoo"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url2);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LastFileMove.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LastFileMove.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

EDIT: I forgot to include the little class I made for the Verifier that I referenced.

```
public class Verifier implements HostnameVerifier 
{

public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        return true;   // mark everything as verified
}
}
```

**Update 5/8/2014**
SSLConext and Verifier are now set up like this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
    .useTLS()
    .loadTrustMaterial(ks)
    .build(); 
X509HostnameVerifier verifier = new AbstractVerifier() 
{
@Override
public void verify(final String host, final String[] 
cns, final String[] subjectAlts) throws SSLException 
{
    verify(host, cns, subjectAlts, true);
}
};
```

And I've gone ahead and changed my HttpClient to a closeable one here:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
sslSocketFactory)
.setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
.setSslcontext(sslContext)
.build();
```

And I'm back to having "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match" errors. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried passing on the SSLContext instance to the [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setSslcontext%28javax.net.ssl.SSLContext%29)? I've had success with that before.

Comment: @vanOekel If I do that then I get the " java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name " error. It seems I would have to pass the verifier to the HttpClientBuilder, but I'm not quite sure how I would do that.

Comment: [setHostnameVerifier](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setHostnameVerifier%28org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier%29) is a start, see if it works if you use the [AllowAllHostnameVerifier](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.html). Apache HttpClient decided to make their own verifier based on [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier.html)

Comment: @vanOekel Isn't an allow all dangerous? Or am I confusing it with something else? Doesn't it open you up for a man in the middle attack?

Comment: Yes, very dangerous and totally unsecure. But it can be used to determine where the problem is during testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea how `Verifier` is implemented but this code snippet demonstrates how one can create a custom hostname verifier none of those shipped with HttpClient fits their needs

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\my.keystore"));
try {
    ks.load(in, "blahblah".toCharArray());
} finally {
    in.close();
}
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .useTLS()
        .loadTrustMaterial(ks)
        .build();
X509HostnameVerifier verifier = new AbstractVerifier() {

    @Override
    public void verify(final String host, final String[] cns, final String[] subjectAlts) throws SSLException {
        verify(host, cns, subjectAlts, true);
    }

};

CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSslcontext(sslContext)
        .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
    .build();
```

Comment: Added the Verifier implementation to my post for clarity, trying to see if your suggestion works now.

Comment: Okay I set up the sslContext and verifier and added them to the CloseableHttpClient as your example shows ... and now I'm back to getting the "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match" error.

Comment: Wait a sec, can I leave that verifier as is do I need to supply values for it? I think that maybe where my issue is.

Comment: But do they really match? What is your target host and what are the common names and alternative names in the certificate?

Comment: They don't match. That was the issue to begin with and I have to overcome it without throwing security down the toilet. I'm trying to access "emailer.driveclick.com" and the owner cn is "www.icebase.com"

Comment: Then i really do not understand the problem you are having. Just make #verify method a no-op and no hostname check will be made